# Minecraft 1.9 not launching

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Earlier today, I opened up minecraft 1.9 on my PC with no problems and played on the server "cubecraft" with my brother.  Now when I try to click play in the launcher, it shows:

"Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release"

Then when I click play again, it opens minecraft but in 1.8.9.  Anyone know how to make it so it will launch 1.9?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I made a new profile and it then seemed to work.